# I am trying to write a function that removes all the odd elements from a given linked-list and also returns an adress of

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I am trying to write a function that removes all the odd elements from a given linked-list and also returns an adress of a new linked list of the odd elements removed. I find this task quite complicated, and I would be happy if you could help to repair or improve my code.

Here is what I've done by far:

```
typedef struct list{
      int data;
      struct  list* next;
} List;


List* removeOddValues(List** source)
{
      List* curr= source;
      List* prev;
      List* odd= NULL;

      while (curr)
      {
        if ((curr->data)%2!=0)
          {
           insertNodeToEnd(&odd, curr->data);
           prev->next = curr->next;
          }
        else
          {
           prev = curr;
           curr= curr->next;
          }
      }
     return odd;
}

List* createNewNode(int newData, List*  next)
{
       List* newNode = (List)calloc(1, sizeof(List));
       newNode->data = newData;
       newNode->next = next;

       return newNode;
}

void insertNodeToEnd(List** list, type  newData) //insert a new node to list //
{
       LNode* newNode = createNewNode(newData, NULL);

    list->next= newNode;

}
```

Comment: 1) `List* curr= source;` --> `List* curr= *source;`... The actual insertion / deletion processing is not done.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  may you explain why?

Comment: type of `source` is `List **`, not `List *`

Comment: How shall I also repair my code?

Comment: Your code is not at the level of correction because the major part is missing. I posted a code example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
List* removeOddValues(List **source){
    List *curr = *source;
    List even = { .next = NULL };
    List *e_curr = &even;
    List odd  = { .next = NULL };
    List *o_curr = &odd;

    while(curr){
        List *next = curr->next;
        curr->next = NULL;

        if(curr->data % 2)// != 0, odd
            o_curr = o_curr->next = curr;//node add to last
        else//even
            e_curr = e_curr->next = curr;

        curr = next;
    }
    *source= even.next;//update source
    return odd.next;
}
```

Comment: sorry, @BLUEPIXY , it does not help me much...I want my code to get improved by using the functions I have written...

Comment: @Gal1988 First of all, You need to complete each lower function. (It is clearly incomplete.)  And there is a flaw in code to delete, code to do loop. Also, you need to release the node from which you left off the link. (I do not think that it is necessary to create a new node)

Comment: but I dont know how to complete them...its quite unclear to me

Comment: how shall I implement it by creating a new node?

Comment: @Gal1988 I can show the code about them, but if you want to do with your logic I think you should write it yourself first. Actually, there are many examples of inserting nodes into the list and deletion examples on this site. Please search it for your own code writing. Then please ask a question again if you encounter problems.

Comment: I must say that I wrote my by being helped by the examples on this site and unfortunately I actually do not have any idea I should repair my code (using the functions I mentioned above), so I guess it would be kind of helpful if you could complete the missing parts...

Comment: @Gal1988 Then, please complete `insertNodeToEnd` first. Also, Which article did you refer to in writing this? Please show the link.

Comment: I used several examples and articles in writing this...there is no specific one... could you write the implementaion of this? it could help me much...

Comment: you wrote there { .next = NULL }    - I have never seen such caption...why did you use such brackets?

Comment: `next` must be initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: it's like   odd-> next = NULL  ?

Comment: yup, `odd.next = NULL;`

Comment: thanks a lot, but can't we implement this code without using so many List integers ? how can we use this function with less integers?

Comment: I don't get you.

Comment: you used 5 List integers in the code written above: curr, even, e_curr, odd, o_curr.  Can we implement this code by using less than 5 five such integers?

Comment: (`List integers` doesn't know the meaning) It is possible but I do not want to spend time for you.

Comment: why? are you angry at me?